# php regular expression for this string

Tags: php, regex

example string:

```
:530 PM PDT THU APR 16 2015
```

start with `":"`, then followed by time like `"530"(5:30)`, then `"AM"` or `"PM"`, then timezone like `"PDT`", then weekday `"THU",` month `"APR"`, date `"16"`, year `"2015"`

Thanks

Comment: the time zone include "HST", "PDT", "AKDT", "MDT", "CDT", "EDT"

Comment: Just explode on whitespace, no?

Comment: Did you check [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
^:\d?\d{3}\s[AP]M\s(?:HST|AKDT|[PCEM]DT)\s[A-Z]{3}\s[A-Z]{3}\s\d?\d\s\d{4}$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aE5zM8/3)

Comment: You can change the first group to `[AP]M` and the second to `(?:HST|AKDT|[PCEM]DT)`